# How to shorten a string empty comparison?

Tags: java

Null is a valid condition in my case. How do I check if a string is empty because that is an error condition ?

I know I can do this, Is there a better way ? If I don't check for null it throws a NPE.

```
String a = ...; 

if(a!=null && a.isEmpty()) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Wrap that code in a method and use this method. But do not reinvent the wheel, this is already accomplished in [`StringUtils.isEmpty(str)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Can you test to see if it IS null (a==null) and go from there?

Comment: null is a valid condition for me and empty is an error condition So I cannot use the StringUtils method ?

Comment: Then keep doing it manually...

Comment: use exception for error condition not ""..

Comment: Wrap it in your own utility method that mirrors StringUtils, but satisfies *your* business logic. I don't really understand the question, though: if you need to check for a combination of null and empty how else would you do it besides checking for a combination of null and empty?!

Comment: I'm kinda curious why `null` is valid and empty is not; what kind of use case is this?

Comment: @DennisMeng looks like a requirement analysis issue =\

Answer (score 3):

As I understand the question, the check you really want is

```
if ("".equals(myString) {
   do stuff ...
}
```

This tests for the string being 0 length and will fall through, without an NPE, for nulls

Comment: Good solution, if (as it seems by the question) `null` is acceptable but `""` is not.

Comment: Not sure but What about `myString = "             <lot of empty spaces here>        ";`?

Comment: By `do stuff` you mean `throw exception` or `report error`, I assume.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I think the important point is the 2 cases are separated here, could easily put `!` in front.

Comment: @iamnotmaynardless I mean the "do stuff" from the original question.  (which I guess is throw an error as I read further)  @Luigu that String with tons of spaces is not empty from the `isEmpty()` point of view.  But, if OP wants to check for that, use `.trim()` on it.

Comment: But then, you can't trim it if `myString` is `null`... :)

Comment: oops - good point!  But I don't think most use cases consider a string containing a bunch of spaces "empty" anyway.

Comment: If you give a second read to the requirement, it is really odd. IMO OP should first process the String to clear any problem using `myString StringUtils.trim(myString);`, then possibly use this way to handle the *exception*. Anyway, as end user, I would not spot a difference between a `null` String (valid) and an empty String (invalid) at least that you're working on a tool to check database rows directly from table, where `NULL` value matters.

Comment: It's funny. I specifically avoid checking strings like this so that I WILL get NPE :).

Comment: Agree that rquirement is odd - as a "Java guy", I much much prefer to use "" to mean unknown, and null as an error or something that never even happens.  But I've worked with database people who are rabid that an empty string is BAD, and you should use null to mean "unknown".

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking if the length of the string is greater than 0;

```
String a = ...; 

if(a!=null && a.length>0) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> null is a valid condition for me and empty is an error condition

If `null` and `not empty` are valid, and `empty` is invalid, this code should be helpful:

```
if(a == null || !a.isEmpty()) 
{
    //do stuff
}
```

or

```
if (!"".equals(a))
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The state `null` is invalid that prevents to check a string emptiness and then do other stuff.

```
String a = ...; 

if (a == null) 
  throw new IllegalStateException("a is null") ;
if (a.isEmpty()) {
    //do stuff
}
```